# Go to beginning of current word and simultanously switch into insert mode

Tags: vim

I know that there's `I` (in normal mode) which goes to the beginning of the line and goes into insert mode.

But does Vim have a built-in/default command to go to the beginning of the **word** my cursor is on *and* simultaneously switch into insert mode?

Comment: There is nothing built-in for that, but you can always roll your own.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah was just curious if there was already a built-in single command for this.

Comment: `I` goes to the beginning of the line, not to the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: Use `bcw` to go to the beginning of the word your cursor is on and delete it and go into insert mode: `b`ackward and `c`hange `w`ord.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press `bi` or `Bi`.
If you think the two keystrokes are too long.... you can create a mapping:

```
nnoremap <F9> bi
```

**Note** that the `<F9>` above is just an example, you can replace it with the key you like.

Comment: add a `w` or `W` to the beginning of your mapping so that you don't go to the beginning of the previous word if you are already at the beginning of the current word.  Still will have an edge-case for if you are on the final word of the file which is a one-character word, though.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons good comment, probably `viwb<esc>i` will help for those cases.